# Copy a string to another string

Tags: c

I am following this algorithm that will copy one string to another string:

```
[S is a source string and T is a target string]
1. Set I = 0
2. Repeat step 3 while S[I] ≠ Null do
3. T[I] = S[I]
4. I = I + 1
[End of loop]
5. Set T[I] = Null
6. Return
```

I have attempted it but it instead removes the first `n` characters from source string relative to length of target string. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char const* stringCopy(char* T, char const* S){
    while(*S){
        *T++ = *S++;
    }
    //*T = 0;
    return T;
}

int main(void){
    char sentence[100] = "some sentence";
    char* again = "another";

    printf("%s", stringCopy(sentence, again));
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Why did you comment-out the essential `//*T = 0;`? (Step 5.)

Comment: You can't return `T` - you've modified it in the loop so it's at the end of the string.

Comment: @WeatherVane I get nothing printed to the console when I do this

Comment: Instead, you get the *wrong* thing printed! With the nul-terminator you get the "empty string". As another comment says, you return the wrong value.

Comment: @John3136 I have attempted returning `S` but again get nothing back

Comment: You've modified `S` too. You need to "remember" the original value of T and return that.

Comment: You need to use *another* variable so you can `return` the original value of `T`.

Comment: @John3136 Something likeso: ```char const* copy = T;
    while(*S){
        *T++ = *S++;
    }
    *T = 0;
    return copy;``` which returns `another`

Answer (score 0):

You return the incremented original pointer T. Make a copy of T for the copy loop and return the original pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char const* stringCopy(char* T, char const* S){
    char *ptr = T;

    while(*ptr++ = *S++);

    return T;
}

int main(void){
    char sentence[100] = "some sentence";
    char* again = "another";

    printf("%s", stringCopy(sentence, again));
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```